# Using multiprocess Pool to load_table_from_dataframe into BigQuery with Python

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I have a script that processes some information, converts it into a Pandas DataFrame, and then uploads it into BigQuery. It is working fine so far, but I'd like to speed up things a little bit.

I'm using multiprocess in order to do so. Everything is fine up to the moment to load the dataframe from Pandas into BigQuery: some time in the process I'd get a "Forbidden: 403 Exceeded rate limits: too many table update operations for this table."

Even when doing 10 task concurrently I'll get this error.

I've tried configuring the BigQuery job to Batch, but that seems to only work for query operations, not for loading ones.

The code is kind of simple: once I get the dataframe, it'll do

```py
job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, table_id)
result = job.result()
```

and it's calling this function by

```py
p = Pool(10)
p.starmap(myfunction, list_of_lists)
p.terminate()
p.join()
```

Any ideas to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find a solution via [this post](https://ronnie-joshua.medium.com/data-pipelines-load-mysql-tables-into-google-big-query-using-python-multiprocessing-pandas-e61d7c4d8573) on Medium so I'm going to paste the code for future reference.

What I did, based on Ronnie Joshua's code, was to use pandas_gbq to write to BigQuery, and in order to do so you have to send your credentials each time.

```
gcp_bq_config = {
    "gcp_credentials": service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        gcp_key_path,
    ),
    "bq_project_id": "sm-data-infra",
    "bq_dataset_id": "my_sql_db_crm",
}


p = Pool(os.cpu_count())
p.starmap(function, 
          tuple(zip(list_to_iterate, repeat(gcp_bq_config))))
p.terminate()
p.join()
```

It works, but eventually I'd get a 403 Exceeded rate limits error, so in the end I had to use another strategy.